# Is exponential growth and decay faster than polynomial growth and decay?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, exponential-function

I know the answer is yes for growth conditions, but I don't see how it's obvious that exponential decay is faster than polynomial decay, say for a polynomial $x^2$.

Comment: What do you mean with "decay" ?

Comment: How fast e^x goes to zero vs. how fast x^2 goes to zero, for instance, @Peter ...

Comment: @Peter, if I look at the limit of x^2 e^x, as x goes to -infinity, two applications of l'hopital's rule easily enough gives 0 as the answer, but asymptotically, how do I know the exponential decays much faster than x^2 grows, as x goes to -infinity? Thanks,

Comment: The limit $0$ implies that in the long-term (in other words asymptotically), the exponential function grows faster.

Comment: yes, @Peter, however, would it be also correct to say that it decays to zero faster than x^2 grows to infinity?  Thanks,

Comment: If you mean $e^{-x}$, yes. Plugging in moderate values already very clearly show that.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much @Peter; have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

The most intuitive way of thinking about it is by considering
$$e^x = \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$$

Given any $p\in\mathbb{R}$, it's easy to see that $x^k = x^{\lceil p \rceil}$ grows faster than $x^p$ as $x$ tends to infinity. But now, whatever $k$ is, there is a term $\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$ in the expansion of $e^x$, so $e^x$ must grow faster than $x^p$ for any $p$.

Similarly, if we can consider the case for $x$ tending to infinity in $e^{-x}$ and see whether that goes to zero faster than a polynomial grows. We simply note that $e^{-x} = \frac{1}{e^x}$. Hence as $e^x$ grows faster than any polynomial, $\frac{1}{e^{x}}$ must decay faster than any polynomial.